# Binding error On ToolTip visibility

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I am trying to bind the visibility property of the ToolTip to the IsEnabled of the Button

```
 <Button Name="bbb" Content="Train" Command="{Binding TrainCmd}" ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True">
      <Button.ToolTip>
          <ToolTip Content="{Binding TrainToolTip}" Visibility="{Binding IsEnabled, Converter={StaticResource InverseBooleanToVisibilityConverter}, ElementName=aaa}">
          </ToolTip>
      </Button.ToolTip>
 </Button>
```

but I get the following error:

> "System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with
>   reference 'ElementName=aaa'. BindingExpression:Path=IsEnabled;
>   DataItem=null; target element is 'ToolTip' (Name=''); target property
>   is 'Visibility' (type 'Visibility')"

I also tried

```
 <Button Content="Train" Command="{Binding TrainCmd}" ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True">
    <Button.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip Content="{Binding TrainToolTip}" Visibility="{Binding IsEnabled, Converter={StaticResource InverseBooleanToVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}"/>
    </Button.ToolTip>
 </Button>
```

but then I get

> "System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with
>   reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor,
>   AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.Button', AncestorLevel='1''.
>   BindingExpression:Path=IsEnabled; DataItem=null; target element is
>   'ToolTip' (Name=''); target property is 'Visibility' (type
>   'Visibility') "

Comment: post your viewmodel also.

Comment: Well, your button name is "bbb", but you want to bind to IsEnabled of "aaa", which can't be found.

Comment: Why do you want to do `ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True"` if you dont want to show tooltip? Why not just use `<Button Content="Train" Command="{Binding TrainCmd}" ToolTip="Test"/>` directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ToolTip does not reside in the same visual tree as it's PlacementTarget.

```
 <Button Name="bbb" Content="Train" Command="{Binding TrainCmd}" ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True">
      <Button.ToolTip>
           <ToolTip Content="{Binding TrainToolTip}" Visibility="{Binding PlacementTarget.IsEnabled, Converter={StaticResource InverseBooleanToVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}">
            </ToolTip>
       </Button.ToolTip>
 </Button>
```